# Displaying a file with a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

For a part of an assignment that I have to do, I am trying to have my program read a certain txt file and display it line for line with my 2D array and another array, but it doesn't print the way I want to. I am trying to debug and I think it is putting the integers in my `studentName` array rather than my 2D array (`score[][]`).

How can I prevent this from happening? Or is it another problem?

This is the txt file I am working with:

```
Johnson 85 83 77 91 76
Aniston 80 90 95 93 48
Cooper 78 82 22 90 73
Gupta 92 83 30 69 87
Blair 23 45 96 38 59
Clark 60 85 45 39 67
Kennedy 77 31 52 74 83
Bronson 93 94 89 77 97
Sunny 79 85 28 93 82
Smith 85 72 49 75 63
```

For now, I just want to output my txt file and make sure all the values are going in their places.

Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string studentName[10] = { " " }, grade[10] = { " " };
    double score[10][6] = { 0 };
    ifstream inFile;
    int i, j;

    inFile.open("arrays.txt");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            inFile >> studentName[i] >> score[i][j];
            cout << studentName[i] << '\t' << score[i][j] << ' ' << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output so far:

```
Johnson 85
83      77
91      76
Aniston 80
90      95
93      48
Cooper  78
82      22
90      73
Gupta   92
83      30
69      87
Blair   23
45      96
38      59
Clark   60
85      45
39      67
Kennedy 77
31      52
74      83
Bronson 93
94      89
77      97
Sunny   79
85      28
93      82
Smith   85
72      49
75      63
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has a bug.

Replace the 'for' part to a piece of code below and it will work

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inFile >> studentName[i];
    cout << studentName[i] << '\t';
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        inFile >> score[i][j];
        cout << score[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Your score array can be save space if you also change it to:

```
double score[10][5] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but my txt is 10x6, so shouldn't it be fine, or do I have to make it one less like `score[9][5]`